# Linq Get count from multiple where condition

Tags: c#, linq

I want something really simple, i want from a list of records to find the ones of a specific date (records can have the same date more than once) and with a specific value,

and count how many of those values exist. So far i'm using this but im not sure if it is the best approach

Here is Records

```
    public class Records
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Record { get; set; }

    }
```

and here is the code

```
 List<Records> records = GetRecords();
 var distinctDates = records.Select(x => x.Date).Distinct().ToList();


 for (int i = 0; i < distinctDates.Count(); i++)
 { 
     statistics.Rows.Add(new object[] { distinctDates[i].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"),
     records.Select(x => x).Where(d => d.Date == distinctDates[i]).Count(x => x.Record == -1).ToString()});
 }
```

I want to know the sum of the appearance of a specific Date and a specific value in Record
So if the database has these values:

11/11/1980, 3

11/11/1980, 3

12/11/1980, 2

I want to get as a result 2 when i will seek for the count of the conditions 11/11/1980 and 3

Comment: Well, you don't need the first `Select`.

Comment: you don't show how i is defined  is this in a loop?  please show the whole loop so we can do it all and get rid of the loop

Comment: probably if you give us some example input data and expected output that would make it easier for us to show you the best way.

Comment: Where does `i` come from; is it an index from a loop?

Comment: Where does `distinctDates[i]` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = records.GroupBy(x => x.Date)
                    .Select(x => new { Date = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```

is  what you want

result will now have a list of dates and count.

if you want a specific value then like this:

```
var result = records.Where(x => x.Record == -1).
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
                    .Select(x => new { Date = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```

To group by the date and not the date time use the date property of the object in the GroupBy statement

```
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Date.Date)
```

Comment: The Dates are in DateTime format but i want "10/1/1980 10:00" and "10/1/1980 10:01" to be grouped as "10/1/1980", can i do that without recreating the records object? (only way i think i can do that is to first make a clone object of "records" and instead of DateTime to use String with .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))

Comment: @CDrosos -- no need to do all that -- see edit above.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a couting of all dates. GroupBy() allows you to distinctly select all dates. Then you can Count() all grouped records with some conditions as you want.

```
records.GroupBy(x => x.Date).Select(x => new
{
    Date = x.Key,
    Count = x.Count(y => y.Record == -1)
}) // This should give you all distinct dates with count
```

Comment: This answer is the direction I was going to suggest but I believe in order to be accurate to the original code you need to move the filtering logic from the trailing `.Where` clause to instead filter the `Count` metric and it needs to check `Record` instead.

Comment: @McAden -- that does not work if you are doing a group by -- you have to filter before the group by like my answer.

Comment: @Hogan It works in a `GroupBy` just fine unless your source is something like EF where it can't be translated properly. Filtering before, as you stated, is an appropriate solution to that though.

Comment: @McAden -- the user only want the results based on his criteria -- putting the filter in the count will give the correct counts (0 for all but ones you want) but will return extra list items which the user does not want to see.

Comment: @Hogan Right, I was more pointing out to this answerer that his solution had incorrect logic, not merely incomplete. Your solution is correct and complete which is why I've already upvoted. I was making an attempt to allow this answerer to correct his solution rather than simply providing a downvote.

Comment: @McAden -- I see.  Then it is probably useful to point out that poster is not trying to filter on a count but instead on `Result == -1`

Comment: Yup, I edited that into my original comment some time ago. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

So given a DateTime date and an int recordValue, you want to count all Records from your recordCollection that have a property Date equal to date and a property Record equal to RecordValue.

How about this:

```
Datetime date = new DateTime(1980, 11, 11);
int recordValue = 3;
var result = recordCollection

    // keep only the records with date and recordValue:
    .Where(record => record.Date == date && record.Record == recordValue)

    // and Count them:
    .Count();
```